# How To Add DATEDIFF & Update Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-difference

Currently I'm practising with `DATEDIFF`. Here are the details:

Table DB1: id, update_time, expire_time, total_diff

Table DB2: id, username

```
SELECT  db2.ID AS ID,
        updatetime.update_time AS Latest_Payment,
        expiretime.expire_time AS Payment_Till
FROM    db2
INNER JOIN db1 ON db2.ID = db1.user_id
LEFT JOIN db1 updatetime ON db2.ID = updatetime.user_id AND updatetime.update_time
LEFT JOIN db1 expiretime ON db2.ID = expiretime.user_id AND expiretime.expire_time
WHERE db2.id >= '0' AND expiretime.expire_time < NOW()
GROUP BY db2.ID;
```

I'm trying to add `DATEDIFF(month, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, updatetime.update_time)` to the code above but got no luck.

What I'm trying to do is to display a table that contain :

```
1. Latest Payment
2. Payment Till
3. Total Diff (How many months payment due)*$80
```

At this moment I am only able to display 'Latest Payment' and 'Payment Till'. May I know how can I add the **DATEDIFF** and it will display it in 1 table?

Sample of data/ table that i try to achive:

```
Name     | Latest Payment (updatetime) | Subscribe Till (expiretime) | Month Due X $80

Arby     | 21/3/2020                   | 21/4/2020      | 80

Casi     | 21/2/2020                   | 21/5/2020      | 0

Will     | 21/2/2020                   | 21/4/2020      | 160
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm baffled.  Are you trying to update a table or return a result set?  What does your data look like?  What logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: You should not update a table with the value of `DATEDIFF(month, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, updatetime.update_time)` because the output of this will be different every time....

Comment: Hi Gordon! What im trying to do is both actually. The sql queries  will do DATEDIFF, update the table and display the data.

Currently the table only showing 'Latest Payment' & 'Payment Till' value with the query that i provide above. So is it possible for the query to do DATEDIFF, update the table and display it in 1 query?

Or is there any ways i can do for the table to show Payment Due value (month). Sample :

Latest Payment : 21/3/2020
Payment Till (Subscribe) : 21/4/2020
Month Due : 1 (As at today)

Comment: Sample data would be helpful to understand it more

Comment: Hi all. Sorry for the confusion. I already edit my question :)